# MongoDB slow facet query using multiple group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, facet

I am working on a project where we will have almost 5 million documents in a collection. And each document's size will be around 18571 bytes having 120 to 150 fields.

I have to return my response in less than 1 second. And mongo query will perform almost 10 to 15 group by in faceted query on maximum 3,00,000 documents.

This is my first time handling this much of data where I have to return responses in real time.

I have implemented indexes and they reduced response time to 5 to 6 seconds but I still need it in less then 1 second.

**Below is sample query:**

```
db.sample.aggregation(
    "$match":{
        "$and":[
            {"is_new": <true/false>},
            {"brand":<some-brand>},
            {"year":{"$gte":<some-year>,"$lte":<some-year>}},
            {"seller_id":{"$in":[<array-of-seller-ids-may-have-40,000-seller-ids>]}}
        ]
    },
    {
        "$facet":{
            "data":[{
                "$project":{
                    "_id":"_id",
                    "brand":"$brand_name",
                    "model":"$model_name",
                    <will have almost 20 keys with lookup>
                }
            }],
            "count":[{"$group":{"_id":"$_id"}},{"$count":"vin_count"}],
            "price":[{"$bucketAuto":{"groupBy":"$price", "buckets":1}}],
            <will have 12-15 group by>
        }
    }
)
```

**Below is sample document:**

```
{
    "_id" : "KNDMC5C11J6394584",
    "brand_id" : 22,
    "brand_name" : "XYZ",
    "abc_id" : 1234567890,
    "city" : "Gurgaon, IN",
    "fluctuation" : 18,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-08-17T06:08:12.940Z"),
    "release_data" : "2018-06-29",
    "seller_name" : "Seller name",
    "seller_price" : 34890,
    "seller_rating" : 4,
    "seller_zip" : "12550",
    "feature1" : "ABC",
    "feature2" : 3300,
    "feature3" : "AB",
    "expected_price" : -1,
    "exterior_color" : "Unknown",
    "registered_dealer" : true,
    "registered_brand" : "ABC",
    "fluctuation_rate" : 20.700000000000003,
    "fluctuation_type" : 2,
    "fluc_type_name" : "Something",
    "has_patents" : false,
    "tested_frequency" : 24,
    "interior_color" : "---",
    "is_certified" : false,
    "is_certified_iso" : false,
    "is_featured" : false,
    "is_new" : true,
    "is_certified_bhel" : false,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -24.08180236816406,
            31.507198333740234
        ]
    },
    "max_input" : 8,
    "feature4" : 3,
    "feature5" : 206,
    "feature6" : "Something",
    "monthly_payment" : 649,
    "msrp" : 34890,
    "feature7" : false,
    "seller_id" : 123567890,
    "product_family_name" : "abc",
    "product_id" : 15,
    "product_name" : "Something",
    "reflection" : "Something",
    "fluc_id" : 2312,
    "fluc_name" : "something something (abc) ac",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-09-11T17:59:36.889Z"),
    "product_damage_category" : "None",
    "year" : 2018,
    "damage_check" : "-",
    "team_size" : "-",
    "Technology" : {
        "camera_unit" : true
    }
}
```

**Below is the explain output**

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "is_new" : true
                        },
                        {
                            "year" : {
                                "$gte" : 2018,
                                "$lte" : 2018
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "sp_id" : {
                                "$in" : [<list of 40,000 seller ids>]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "test_collection.col",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "is_new" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "year" : {
                                    "$lte" : 2018
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "year" : {
                                    "$gte" : 2018
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "sp_id" : {
                                    "$in" : [<list of 40,000 seller ids>]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "is_new" : 1,
                                "year" : 1,
                                "sp_id" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "is_new_1_year_1_sp_id_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "is_new" : [ ],
                                "year" : [ ],
                                "sp_id" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "is_new" : [
                                    "[true, true]"
                                ],
                                "year" : [
                                    "[2018.0, 2018.0]"
                                ],
                                "sp_id" : [
                                    "[47590.0, 47590.0]",
                                    "[48333.0, 48333.0]",
                                    "[51333.0, 51333.0]",
                                    <range of 40,000 seller_ids>
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$facet" : {
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "$project" : {
                            "_id" : "$_id",
                            "brand_name" : "$brand_name",
                            "feature1" : "$feature1",
                            "feature2" : "$feature2",
                            "feature3" : "$feature3",
                            "feature4" : "$feature4",
                            "feature5" : "$feature5",
                            "feature6" : "$feature6",
                            "feature7" : "$feature7",
                            "feature8" : "$feature8",
                            "feature9" : "$feature9",
                            "feature10" : "$feature10",
                            "feature11" : "$feature11",
                            "feature12" : "$feature12",
                            "feature13" : "$feature13",
                            "feature14" : "$feature14",
                            "feature15" : "$feature15",
                            "feature16" : "$feature16",
                            "feature17" : "$feature17",
                            "feature18" : "$feature18",
                            "feature19" : "$feature19",
                            "feature20" : "$feature20"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "count" : [
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$_id"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : {
                                "$const" : null
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$project" : {
                            "_id" : false,
                            "count" : true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature1" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature1" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature1",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature1"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature2" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature2" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature2",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature2"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature3" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature3" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature3",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature3"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature4" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature4" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature4",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature4"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature5" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature5" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature5",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$fuel"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature6" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature6" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature6",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature6"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature7" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature7" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature7",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature7"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature8" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature8" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature8",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature8"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature9" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature9" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature9",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature9"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature10" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature10" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$feature10",
                            "name" : {
                                "$first" : "$feature10"
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "_id" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature11" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "feature11" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$bucketAuto" : {
                            "groupBy" : "$feature11",
                            "buckets" : 1,
                            "output" : {
                                "count" : {
                                    "$sum" : {
                                        "$const" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "feature12" : [
                    {
                        "$bucketAuto" : {
                            "groupBy" : "$feature11",
                            "buckets" : 1,
                            "output" : {
                                "count" : {
                                    "$sum" : {
                                        "$const" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If this information is not complete for the solution. I will provide more.

I am stuck on this from last 1 month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without examples of documents in the collection, full query, result of .explain() and resources utilisation stats there is nothing to advise but remind that each field in the facet is an aggregation pipeline, i.e. having 12-15 fields you actually run 12-15 sub-queries. Even tho they are executed in parallel, they still compete for resources, so aiming <1sec in total you need an individual sub-query to take no more 200 milis. Also keep in mind that aggregation framework can benefit from indexes only on the first stage - in your case $match.

Comment: @AlexBlex I am aware that indexes are only applied to first stage of aggregation pipeline. I have already created indexed based on the $match query in first stage. But the data which we get after first stage is so huge that facet query fails to perform fast.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added sample document and explain output

Comment: It looks like you are currently using this index: is_new_1_year_1_sp_id_1
You can try and create another index that is based of all 4 of your match query search columns: is_new, year, brand and seller_id.

Comment: I believe sorting within subqueries cause more delay than grouping. You can slightly optimise it by using projection stage between $match and $facet - it seems you don't use anything but `featureXX` fields in the facet. Don't expect miracles tho. It is still 12-15 groupings and in-memory sorts. Double check your server has enough memory/CPU. If you really need all these data that quick you may need to pre-aggregate it.

Comment: @mdewit You are right on indexing. I am using the same index (is_new_1_year_1_sp_id_1). I have also created another index including brand. And I specify index in my query hint based on match query. But it still take time.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added projection after $match stage. But it is still taking same time

Comment: @AlexBlex You said I can pre-aggregate it. Can you be specific ?

Comment: Preaggreagtion is a technic to compute aggregated metrics at time of document modification, rather than at query time. It reduces query time to few millis but works only if you know all your `featureXX` axes beforehand, which seems to be your case.
It's described in https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/ Don't be confused with the "MMAPv1" warning. It applies to preallocation part of the page only. Another example for time-series data preaggreagtion: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb.